# Excel vba change value from one sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I have two named sheets and I want to change value from one sheet to another with following syntax; however I get Type Mismatch Error. Can anyone look into this and assist me?

Named Sheets: wks1 and wks2

```
wks1.cells(1,1).value=wks2.cells(1,3).value
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show where you set the worksheets? This one line does not appear to have any problems.

Comment: How have you set the object variables for `wks1` and `wks2`? They need to be set like this: `Dim wks1 As Worksheet  Set wks1 = Thisworkbook.Sheets("SheetNameHere")`

Comment: @Jordan thanks!, This is where I missed. All set!

Comment: @Jordar One more question, when I name the sheet1 as wks1 in "Microsoft Excel Object", do we still need to set the worksheet?

Comment: no, but you should probably keep it as "Sheet1" and change your code to `Sheet1.Cells...` to avoid confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One example:

```
Sub Manish()
    Dim wks1 As Worksheet, wks2 As Worksheet

    Set wks1 = Sheets("wks1")
    Set wks2 = Sheets("wks2")

    wks1.Cells(1, 1).Value = wks2.Cells(1, 3).Value
End Sub
```